# Oracle/SQL - Dynamic columns based on parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

so I'm trying to build a data model for a headcount report that allows the user to select what he wants the headcount to calculate by(Dynamic column). I tried querying the script below (this is just an example, the real script has several counts and percentages) And the system is stuck on processing like its in a loop. My list of values range from 1-5. Ive also tried to make a fixed list of values and put the queries for the grouping column in the values, which also created a endless processing. Any ideas?

```
(SELECT test1.test1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id.personid)
    FROM
    table_identifiers id,
    (SELECT DISTINCT
    (CASE WHEN :P_COLUMN = 1 THEN te.ethnicities
    WHEN :P_COLUMN = 2 THEN tc.companyname
    ELSE NULL END) AS test1
    FROM
    table_ethnicities te,
    table_companies tc
    WHERE 1=1

    ) test1
    GROUP BY test1.test1)
```

Comment: Besides the Cartesian join, note that the comma-separated `FROM` clause is discouraged, and should not be used, in preference for explicitly listing out `JOIN`s (and including as many conditions as possible with the `JOIN` in the `ON` clause, not as part of the `WHERE`).  Part of your problem may also be grouping by a dynamic column - although the optimizer may be smart enough to lift the constant (would require profiling).  If not, you'd get better results with dynamic SQL, but that's more error-prone.

Comment: I know, I do it more out of necessity to shorten my queries a little and keep them to a manageable level as far as the ability to quickly sift through and locate pieces of script. Unfortunately I work for a huge corporation that likes to limit my access to everything so I have to program over the oracle provided web-browser desktop. Instead of using a nifty program even if I had some color coding on the words, would be nice or a way to space data out but no. So I keep it as simplistic as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well on the first look you have a cartesian join in you most **inner** test1 query

```
FROM
    table_ethnicities te,
    table_companies tc
    WHERE 1=1
```

Then you have a second caressian join between **table_identifiers** and **test1** query.

```
FROM
    table_identifiers id,(
...
) test1
    GROUP BY test1.test1)
```

So this is potential reason for low perfomance of this query.

To solve problem in test1 query I suggest to use UNION ALL operator, like:

```
(SELECT test1.test1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id.personid)
    FROM
    table_identifiers id,
    (SELECT DISTINCT te.ethnicities AS test1
          FROM table_ethnicities te
          WHERE :P_COLUMN = 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DISTINCT tc.companyname 
          FROM table_companies tc
          WHERE :P_COLUMN = 2
    ) test1
    GROUP BY test1.test1)
```

To fix second cartesian join, you should add join condition.

Comment: This did solve my problem with the constant loading now for some reason my companyname column is not distinct even though I used DISTINCT I wonder why. But this is something I can probably figure out on my own. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @K. Layton. You have duplicates because you don't have join condition between the output of test1 query and table_identifiers table. This produces cartesian join and subsequently duplicates company name in final output.